# How to enter text other than english(like Malayalam,hindi..) in a.php page

Tags: operating-system

I am using dream weaver for creating php pages, and 
I set the charset=utf-8

My key board have only English letters, then how can i enter text in different language(like Malayalam,hindi..).

if i copy paste different language text from any other site it will work.

But how can i enter my own text?

Comment: If im not wrong this question is related to OS usage not php? :)
Anyways add keyboard input methods (can be done in control panel > region and language settings)

Comment: Has nothing to do with PHP or HTML

Comment: Firstly, you have put this in wrong forum, secondly, if you are dealing with php you should know how your os works in it's simplest form. Have changed the tags for you

Comment: This is off topic, and is not relevant neither to php nor to html. You're trying to change the Input Method Editor, and that depends on your OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to switch your keyboard into whichever language you wish to use,

[How to change keyboard language in Windows](http://www.conversationexchange.com/resources/keyboard-language.php)

if it is just for odd characters you can use &codes to put in individual letters

Answer (score 1):

Change the language on your operating system. In Windows it is done in Control Panel -> Language and Region.. I think.

Answer (score 0):

you can use transilitration.

There is a website which you don't need require to download any software or change on ur desc.

just got to [vanmaram.com](http://www.vanmaram.com/) type and copy paste to your editing page

Comment: @Athimannil thank you very much 

it is really useful for me my laptop locked with admin. 
this chatfitness.com is usefull for me 


thanks